# Custom Search Result Page displaying only 1 result.

Tags: wp-query, search

I'm trying to build a custom search results page. The problem I'm running into is that when I enter a search term ; say 'gaming', it will only return one result, being the latest result. I have my blog setup to display only one article at a time. However, I found a way to circumvent the search results page  by logging into wp-admin -> settings -> reading -> and changing the blog page displays one post to say for example 10.

Then when I try searching for gaming it returns more than one result (it'll give me 10). However, I don't want this. I want my sites blog page to only show one article, and the results page to display more than one result. How can I go about fixing this?

This is what my `search.php` looks like. I created a `searchpage.php` and am including it using PHP to grab the `search.php`

Thanks! :)

```
    <!-- SEARCH PAGE -->
    <div id="search-results" class="wrapper" role="search">

<h2> Search Results</h2>

<!-- COUNT RESULTS -->
<div class="results">
    <?php
    /* Search Count */
    $allsearch = &new WP_Query("s=$s&showposts=-1"); 
    $key = wp_specialchars($s, 1);
    $count = $allsearch->post_count; 
    _e('');
    _e('"<span class="search-terms">');
    echo $key;
    _e('</span>"'); 
    _e(' &mdash; found ');
    echo $count . ' '; 
    _e('articles');
    wp_reset_query(); ?>

</div>
<!-- / COUNT RESULTS -->

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- LIST RESULTS -->
<section>   
    <h3>
        <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to 
        <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> - 
        <span class="search-time"><?php the_time('F, j, Y') ?></span>
        </li>
    </h3>
</section>
<!-- / LIST RESULTS -->

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<!-- 404 SEARCH -->
<div class="404-search">
<?php _e("Oops... We couldn't find what you were searching for. Please try again"); ?>
</div>
<!-- / 404 SEARCH -->

<?php endif; ?>

     </div>

     <!-- / SEARCH PAGE -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

to

```
<?php if ($allsearch->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while ($allsearch->have_posts()) : $allsearch->the_post(); ?>
```

because otherwise you don't utilize your custom query.

See [WP_Query Usage](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage).

Also  call `wp_reset_query();` after the Loop.

See [wp_reset_query Description](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query#Description).

Actually, you don't need `wp_reset_query();` because you use custom `WP_Query` object and don't need to reset `global` `$wp_query`.

Comment: Awesome that did the job! Thanks! I tried look all over Google and I couldn't find anything related to this. Thanks a bunch! :3